# How reliable is ordering in a Postgres array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have `store` table:

```
CREATE TABLE store(
  id SERIAL,
  product_ids INT[],
  product_prices NUMERIC[]
)
```

For example:

```
id | product_ids | product_prices 
----------------------------------
1  | {12, 4}     | {100, 202.5}
```

Which means that the price for the product with ID `12` is `100`, and the price for product ID `4` is `202.5`. IDs in the `product_ids` array are unique.

If product `id=4` has a new price, for example `199`, I update it this way:

```
UPDATE store SET 
product_prices [idx(product_ids , 4)] = 199
WHERE id = ?
```

The order of elements in these arrays is very important. I never sort these arrays, maybe just add a new product_id and the appropriate price using `array_append()`.

So the question is: How reliable is the ordering in a Postgres array? Is there a chance that somehow Postgres will sort the array or exchang element positions itself someday?

P.S.  I need to make this with arrays, I don't want to use some other table with columns `store_id`, `product_id`, `product_price` etc.

Comment: What is the reason for this de-normalized design? You can't even have proper foreign keys with this model. Or prevent the same product to appear twice with different prices. And it will get quite complicated if you ever need to run (real-world) reports on it.

Comment: Reason is that quantity of self `stores`, is huge, approximately 500 000, but products for each store, would be not so big (max 5000), so if store this data with normal database design, e.i. in different table, the rows count will be very huge, in this case, `product_ids` and `product_prices`  arrays will be contain maximum 5000 element, no more.

Comment: `Or prevent the same product to appear twice with different prices` - before adding product id to `product_ids` array, I check, if there exists this ID in array, i do price update as I show in question , if not, then I add new product id and its price at the end of appropriate arrays

Comment: `And it will get quite complicated if you ever need to run (real-world) reports on it` - because of  reports will be from only one concrete store (and not from several stores together), executing data and making report will be easy, because of little amount of products for this concrete store

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is reasons of this de-normalized design :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Postgres won't change the order of your arrays on its own. If a database did that, we would all be in a lot of trouble.